# Rails restful routes and singular resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I am having a problem with restful routes and singular resources, originally I had this code in the show view on my account resource.

```
<%= link_to book.title, book_path(:search => book.title) %>
```

and it worked fine, then I changed account to be a singular resource, e.g

from

```
map.resources :accounts
```

to

```
map.resource :account
```

and now I get the error ...

```
book_url failed to generate from {:search=>"Dracula", :controller=>"books", :action=>"show"}, expected: {:controller=>"books", :action=>"show"}, diff: {:search=>"Dracula"}
```

remove the view line of code, and everything works fine. Also changing it to

```
<%= link_to book.title, :controller => "books", :action => "show", :search => book.title %>
```

makes it work.

I have created a standalone rails application demonstrate my problem in isolation http://github.com/jowls/singular_resource_bug

Is this a bug? brought about through some combination of singular resources and restful routes?

This was on rails 2.3.10

thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why are you using `:search => book.title` when you have the book resource itself? Why not use `link_to book.title, book_path(book)`, assuming you wish to link the user to the book resource itself.

Comment: It's a contrived example to illustrate the bug, not particularly well thought out i admit. In the real application i am creating a link to search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account singleton resource is a red herring. Your problem is just that you're missing the `:id` parameter of books_url (which is always the first argument). You can pass in additional arguments like so:

```
book_url(book, :search => 'Dracula') # book.id would also work here
```

But there must be a book. That's just how Rails's resource routes work.

It's strange if this worked before, because you should have been getting this error on your `books` resource the whole time.

An easy way to refactor your code to work around this would be to add a line to your controller's show action:

```
class BooksController < ActionController::Base

  def show
    # If :search is blank, populate it with :id's value
    params[:search] ||= params[:id]

    # your code ...
  end

end
```

Then just pass the search/title string in as the first argument to `book_url`/`book_path`:

```
# "Dracula" will be passed to your controller as params[:id]
book_path("Dracula")
```

Alternatively you can override the default/generated route like this:

```
map.resources :books

# Explicit named routes take precedence over generated ones
map.book '/books/:search', :controller => 'books', :action => 'show'
```

One caution against the latter idea is that it *prevents* you from using an :id parameter instead—it makes :search the default REST identifier, so if you tried using :id you'd have your original error, just with a different param.

I've tested these solutions in the example app you posted and they all seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, i particularly like your last suggestion. The way i have managed to overcome this problem is by using the index action instead of the show action to display the search results. books_path(:search => book.title), it all works perfectly then.